# Register application for consuming MS Graph Onenote API in production environment

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api

I am integrating Onenote with my application. I am using MS Graph API's for getting data from Onenote. To consume the api's I am generating the token as mentioned at link [get auth tokens](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_register_app_v2).

I am registering my application at [MS application registration portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/)

How can I specify that this particular application is registered to be used in production environment. Since the latency for API would differ from MS graph side for sandbox and production environment

Comment: What do you mean by sandbox environment? If you call graph.microsoft.com you reach the production graph API.

Comment: By sandbox environment I meant test environment .While registering application in order to access the API do I need to specify that I will be using the application in my production environment

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to tell the application registration whether the registration is for your test or production environment.

You may use the same registration for both test and production, or you can create two registrations. Whichever you prefer.

If you use one registration, and your app is a web application, you will need to add the reply URLs of all the environments to the registration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling graph.microsoft.com and getting content from OneNote that you can view in the client, you are already calling the production environment. There is no such thing as a sandbox environment that I'm aware of, other than the one in the Graph Console/Explorer.

Comment: The application registration process will also be same for my test and production environment ? Usually API limits vary as per environments so do I need to explicitly inform that this registered app will be used in production